# FB SDK redirecting me to different app after confirm login

Tags: ios, facebook, fbsdk

I have 2 versions of same app in my iphone with different Bundle ID but same Fb APP ID.

Case-1 : When i try to log in through app-1, after confirm login, I get redirected to app-2 login page.

Case-2 : When i try to log in through app-2, after confirm login, everything works fine. I get redirected to same app.

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: what is the solution? My app is rejected... Don't know why.. 

In my all device working perfectly but when i submitted the app then facebook redirected another app when I login.What is the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try following solution

This problem occurs due to same url scheme use for facebook login in app

1. You need set different URL scheme for both app .
2. Remove that app and check it will redirect correct application.

Comment: If i change url scheme, then i have to change fb id also, because if fb_id = 1234XXX, then url scheme is fb1234XXXX, if i won't use same fb_id in URL scheme then app will crash.

Comment: what i understand by your answer is this....sorry if u want to convey something else.

Comment: did you try second solution ?

Comment: if second solution works then you need to create another app id in facebook developer account and use it for your second app .

Comment: you can't use same app id for different app ... if you want to use same id then you also use same url scheme for both that reason your app get crashed  .

Comment: Yes, if i remove app-2 from iphone, then app-1 is working fine. But if app-2 is present in iphone, then it is redirecting me to app-2.

Comment: then you need to register new app in facebook developer and use that id and urlscheme for another app.